# Preferences reports wrong version for some installed apps

Tags: updates, windows-11, version, winget

For a few of my apps, the preferences/apps control panel shows an incorrect (outdated) version. `winget` reports the same thing. For example, I have installed OBS Studio 28.0.2, but `winget` thinks it's 25.0.8.

Same thing with another software suite (Topaz AI): Three of the four apps show the correct version, but one app is reported as v6.0.0 (and `winget` proposes updating to 6.1.0) whereas I have installed 6.2.0...

I don't have more than one version installed (like one in Program Files and one in AppData or something like that), and I'm the only user on my machine.

Any idea how/why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to know what the different tools use to determine app version. What research have you done regarding this?

Comment: According to the link @harrymc provided, `winget` uses the ARP (Add and Remove Programs) information, which is tied to the Registry keys. So it's a probably a problem on the developer's side for OBS/Topaz Gigapixel (the latter have confirmed this and suggested a workaround (using the full installer instead of the in-program updater), and this worked for both programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should complain to OBS Studio Support, although it might not be
entirely their fault.

For example, the bug-report
[Some packages don't provide Version info, and winget upgrade constantly reports those #1255](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1255)
relates that winget has difficulty reading the version information of some
packages, so shows their version as "Unknown".

In your case, this same problem might result in the wrong version number
found, although on the other hand it could be the fault of OBS Studio not
having updated the version number in the package.

(Just to note that a user in that bug-report has solved his problem
by moving on to Chocolatey.)

Comment: Running the full installers (as opposed to the in-program update mechanism) fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!